# Node/Mongoose not sending SendGrid email due to mongoose promise warning

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I am getting this error when I upgraded to mongoose 4.13.8 and sendgrid 6.1.4. Trying to understand how to fix the problem on my side or if I need to revert to a previous version of one or both?

```
(node:4862) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default promise library) is deprecated, plug in your own promise library instead: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html
(node:4862) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Unauthorized
at Request.http [as _callback] (node_modules/@sendgrid/client/src/client.js:124:25)
at Request.self.callback (node_modules/request/request.js:186:22)
at Request.emit (events.js:159:13)
at Request.<anonymous> (node_modules/request/request.js:1163:10)
at Request.emit (events.js:159:13)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (node_modules/request/request.js:1085:12)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:254:19)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:164:20)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1062:12)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:152:19)
(node:4862) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:4862) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

The offending line seems to be coming from `node_modules/@sendgrid/client/src/client.js:124:25`, right?

That line is here:
https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-nodejs/blob/master/packages/client/src/client.js#L124

Any idea how to fix? I guess I'll rollback both until I better understand the problem! Thanks in advance!

Comment: mongoose and sendgrid are unrelated things doing unrelated functions.

Comment: Also please consider mongoose mpromise depreciation warning and plug in the promise library of your choice like bluebird.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the cause of this issue. I guess "reading between the lines" you can see the `Error: Unauthorized`. For whatever reason, the `process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY` line does not work for me. When I put the actual key in that line `sgMail.setApiKey(_MYKEY_);` it started working.